# Lower and upper pointwise dimensions of a measure $\mu$ and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$ and $x \in \mathbb R^d$, we define the lower and upper pointwise dimensions of a Borel probability measure $\mu$ at $x$ by (here $B(x,r)$ is the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$)

$$\underline{\dim}_x:= \liminf_{r \to 0} \frac{\log(\mu(B(x,r)))}{\log(r)},$$

and

$$\overline{\dim}_x:= \limsup_{r\to 0} \frac{\log(\mu(B(x,r)))}{\log(r)}.$$

In a paper I am reading, the authors claim that we can replace the liminf and limsup on the right hand sides by the lininf and limsup over any sequence $r_n \to 0$ with $r_n/r_{n+1}$ bounded. Namely

$$\liminf_{r \to 0} \frac{\log(\mu(B(x,r)))}{\log(r)}=\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(\mu(B(x,r_n)))}{\log(r_n)},$$

and similarly for limsup. I wonder how to prove this for any Borel probability measure. Note that the measure $\mu$ here can be very weird. (If $\mu$ is a Lebesgue measure or point mass at $x$, then liminf=limsup)

Comment: I suspect this is related to *Proposition 4.1* on p. 54 of Falconer's [**Fractal Geometry**](https://www.amazon.ae/dp/0471922870) (1990) or *Theorem 2.3(3)* on p. 19 of Pesin's [**Dimension Theory in Dynamical Systems**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0226662225), but I don't have time now to dive into this and attempt an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible proof that I am not completely sure:

For convenience, write

$$\frac{\log(\mu(B(x,r)))}{\log(r)}=\frac{\log(1/\mu(B(x,r)))}{\log(1/r)}.$$

Then for $r_{n+1}<r<r_{n}<C r_{n+1}$ (with $r_n$ dicreasing) we have the inequality

$$ \frac{\log(1/\mu(B(x,r_{n})))}{\log(C/ r_{n})} \le
\frac{\log(1/\mu(B(x,r_{n})))}{\log(1/r_{n+1})} 
\le \frac{\log(1/\mu(B(x,r)))}{\log(1/r)} \le 
\frac{\log(1/\mu(B(x,r_{n+1})))}{\log(1/r_n)} \le
\frac{\log(1/\mu(B(x,r_{n+1})))}{\log(1/C r_{n+1})}
$$

Now taking $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ "yields the answer" (?).

The part that I am not completely sure about is that whether one can really squeeze a function between two sequences and take the limit w.r.t. different variables. Please let me know if this is correct (and your justification).